# Brand new to data science - Making sure I understand sets

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, dictionary, set

I am trying to assign alpha-numeric codes to objects in a dataframe and I'm wondering if I'm on the right track. The mission is to categorize a list of organizations based on NTEE designations. For example, anything that could be considered healthcare would get an 'E' designation and a numerical designation based on more specific factors. Just to get started, though, I thought of creating a list of possible flags for healthcare. Based on my very limited working knowledge of python, I've come up with this:

```
healthcare = {'healthcare', 'health care', 'health', 'hospital', 'medical'}
for x in healthcare:
    new_healthcare = ('E')
    print(new_healthcare)
```

And this kind of gives me what I'm looking for. This prints

```
E
E
E
E
E
E
```

The next thing I'd like to do with this is apply this to a particular column 'A' in a dataframe and create a new column 'B' containing 'E' in any row where 'A' contains any value in the set 'healthcare'. So two questions: 1) For the very barebones code I'm running, is there an easier way to produce the same result; and 2) How might we be able to run this loop through a particular column in a dataset and use it to create a new column?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and how to provide a [mre]. If you intend on asking many pandas questions, here's a useful link: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953) More people will write good answers if all the relevant information needed to reproduce your problem is given in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have much to do with sets at all. You need to *look up* the value of your code based on the value of your column `A`.

Say you had a dataframe like so:

```
    org         type
0   Hospital1   hospital
1   Hospital2   hospital
2   UrgentCare1 healthcare
3   Doctor1     medical
4   Bookstore1  business
```

code:

```
l = [{'org': 'Hospital1', 'type': 'hospital'}, {'org': 'Hospital2', 'type': 'hospital'}, {'org': 'UrgentCare1', 'type': 'healthcare'}, {'org': 'Doctor1', 'type': 'medical'}, {'org': 'Bookstore1', 'type': 'business'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

You could create a lookup dictionary, where the keys are the items you want to look up, and the values are the result you want. For example:

```
code_lookup = {
        'healthcare': 'E', 
        'health care': 'E',
        'health': 'E', 
        'hospital': 'E', 
        'medical': 'E',
        'business': 'B',
        'other': 'O'
     }
```

You could convert this to its own dataframe:

```
code_lookup_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(code_lookup, orient='index', columns=['Designation'])
```

which gives:

```
            Designation
healthcare            E
health care           E
health                E
hospital              E
medical               E
business              B
other                 O
```

Then, you could simply lookup the values of the Designation column in `code_lookup_df` for the values in the original `df["type"]`, and assign that to the column `Designation` in the original dataframe:

```
df['Designation'] = code_lookup_df.loc[df["type"], "Designation"].to_list()
```

`df` is now:

```
           org        type Designation
0    Hospital1    hospital           E
1    Hospital2    hospital           E
2  UrgentCare1  healthcare           E
3      Doctor1     medical           E
4   Bookstore1    business           B
```